# Allowing Allies to free one from Entangle and Web

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions

Among spells that restrain creatures, most require those restrained to free themselves while others expressly allow allies to free them (either directly or by using the Help action to assist the restrained creature).

**I suggest that allies be explicitly allowed to free restrained creatures from both *entangle* and *web* as a result of the ally's own actions,** rather than just as a Help reaction to the restrained creature's next attempt.

I am wondering if allowing this is considered unbalancing, if it goes against a specific design intent, or if it has already been ruled on in an online source.

*Spells that provide a mechanic for allies to free those restrained*:
Ensnaring strike (1st), Maximilian's Earthen Grasp (2nd) [Help only], Snare (1st)

*Spells that require those restrained to free themselves:*
Entangle (1st) [incorrect, should be on the list above as Help only], Evard's Black Tentacles (4th), Flesh to Stone (6th), Imprisonment (9th), Mental Prison (6th), Prismatic Spray (7th), Prismatic Wall (9th), Telekinesis (5th), Watery Sphere (4th), Web (2nd) [incorrect, should be on the list above as Help only], Whirlwind (7th level), Wrath of Nature (5th)

Note that all of the spells that allow for assistance are first or second level, while all of those that do not allow assistance are 4th and above *except for entangle and web*. [incorrect]  From a power perspective entangle and web seem like they more naturally belong among the first group.

The webbing of the giant spider *monster* permits allies to cut free those restrained - this seems like a good model for the web spell.

The net *weapon* allows allies to either pull one free or cut one free - this seems like a good model for the entangle spell.

**Am I missing a balance issue, a design intent, or an errata?**

Or am I correct that entangle and web should have been written like some other first and second level spells to allow restrained creatures to be freed by allies?

A comment including any spells that restrain that I have missed would be appreciated as well.

Comment: My initial question contained a factual misunderstanding for which I appreciate Szega's correction.  I believe the correction could have been better expressed as a comment rather than an answer.  I have edited the question to better ask what I was really interested in, taking advantage of Szega's correction.

Comment: Right, but that factual misunderstanding is a reasonable one to have made, and Szega’s answer was a good answer. I’d prefer to see a new question than a substantive change that invalidates good answers. But that’s why I’ve flagged for moderator attention. Additionally, Szega’s answer answered the question as it was, and we have a [policy against answering in the comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Comment: I believe my question was, "Should web and entangle allow an ally to free someone else?"  Szegas response was "You missed that those spells allow an ally to help someone free themselves."  While true and a valued correction, I do not think it was an answer to my question.

Comment: I've rolled this back to the original version. When a correction is at the core at the issue it should be addressed as an answer. However, I agree with you that it doesn't fully answer the concern (I think) you have, but you should further clarify what that is. Specifically as I understood you, the change you're looking to do to the spells is to let allies use an action to free the restrained creature. You should clearly emphasize that is what you meant by "explicitly allowed to free".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Those spells use a check to free yourself too

> A creature restrained by the plants/webs can use its action to make a
> Strength check against your spell save DC. (PHB 238/288)

Thus making them eligible for Help, just like *grasp*. Also, the conjured *web* is flammable, so your friendly neighborhood <s>pyromaniac</s> sorcerer can free you with a bit of charring.

Comment: The question is also (arguably mostly) interested in letting allies use their action to free the creature and not just help, so it would be very useful to also address that aspect.